# Red5 Simple Stream

Tags: streaming, red5

I am attempting to run a Red5 server to do something pretty simple.  I want to stream from my local computer and have others view with an flash-based RTMP client across the web.  I would like to password protect the server (so only I can stream to it), but I would like anyone to be able to connect to it.  Given the apparent robustness of Red5 this seems like it would be fairly easy to set up.

I have used the oflaDemo to successfully stream and view my content, but I am ready to start my own VERY simple "application" in Red5 to achieve this.  I am somewhat overwhelmed and don't know where to start because the documentation seems to have been written by someone apparently very much smarter than I am.

First of all, is using Red5 overkill?  Is there a more simple approach that I can use to stream my content out to my web server?  I am not trying to transcode or use objects or anything very complicated at all.  Just use Red5 to get my content out there (Adobe Flash Media Server is VERY straightforward, but looking for an open-source alternative).

Second of all, if Red5 is the way I need to go, where can I go to learn to create a very simple "application" to stream out to the web?

My server is a dedicated box running Debian GNU Linux 7.0.  Thanks!